# Open Google Spreadsheet in full screen with app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, fullscreen

I need to open a *google spreadsheet* in full screen with app script on event `onOpen()`, any suggestions to do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done. Scripts cannot control the mode of the browser in which a spreadsheet is shown. The most you can do is to use [`Browser.msgBox`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgboxprompt) to ask the user to enter the full-screen mode when the spreadsheet is opened.

```
function onOpen() {
  Browser.msgBox('Please switch to full screen mode by pressing F11');
}
```

Comment: Google Sheets has "another full screen": Menu View > Full screen :)

Comment: True, but I believe the answer stays the same: a script can't turn this on.

Comment: I agree but also I was wondering to which of both kind of Full screen was the OP talking about.